# DevExpress print preview RightToLeft

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am using TcxGrid and set RTL, but printview is totally reverse and the data in rows is left aligned. How can set setting in print preview RightToLeft?

Platform : WinForms
Version : DevExpress 18.2.8
IDE : Delphi 10.1 Berlin

Comment: They are slowly adding BiDi support to various components but it looks like they have not gotten to the print preview window or component printer. Support ticket from a year ago on this : https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t811260/support-bidi-mode-in-tdxcomponentprinter